# How to locate an element in a ExtJS pop window

Tags: extjs, selenium-webdriver

The system under test uses the ExtJS Framework to create dynamic pages.

The scenario is when a user clicks a button on the main browser page a pop window appears, I want to enter text in a textfield on this child window.

The only element I have located was the outer frame, I then tried to use this to locate textfield I wanted, but it failed.

***Element Code***

input type="text" size="16" autocomplete="off" id="name" name="name" class="x-     form-text x-form-field x-form-invalid x-form-focus" style="width: 233px;"

I have tried the code below:

```
            WebElement parentObj = getDriver().findElement(
            By.cssSelector("#parentObj "));

            WebElement newObj = parentObj.findElement(
            By.xpath("//input[@id='name']"));
            newObj.click();
            newObj.sendKeys("Text to enter");
```

Can anyone help map elements in child extJS screens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should stick to CSS selectors as much as you can:

```
parentObj.findElement(By.cssSelector('input[name="name"]'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your popup window is present inside an iframe, you need to switch to that iframe first.

use the below code to switch to iframe, then you can use your existing selector.

```
var iframe = driver.findElement(By.TagName("iframe"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframe);


WebElement parentObj = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#parentObj "));

WebElement newObj = parentObj.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='name']"));
newObj.click();
newObj.sendKeys("Text to enter");
```